Django GeneratedField as ForeignKey with referential integrity
I'm trying to create a generated field that is also a foreign key to another table, while maintaining referential integrity at the database level.
Basically, I'm trying to have the same effect as the following SQL, but in Django
CREATE TABLE parent(
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE child(
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  data JSONB,
  parent_id TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (data->>'parent') STORED REFERENCES parent(id)
);

I have successfully managed to create the generated field using Django 5.0 GeneratedField
class Parent(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)

class Child(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    data = models.JSONField()
    parnet_id = models.GeneratedField(expression=models.fields.json.KT('data__parent'), output_field=models.TextField(), db_persist=True)

Now the problem is: how can I make this field also a foreign key? Because using ForeignKey would create a new column in the database that is not generated.
I tried using ForeignObject, since it supports using an existing field as a foreign key, but the foreign key constraint was not created at the database level.
class Parent(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)

class Child(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    data = models.JSONField()
    parnet_id = models.GeneratedField(expression=models.fields.json.KT('data__parent'), output_field=models.TextField(), db_persist=True)
    parent = models.ForeignObject(Parent, from_fields=['parnet_id'], to_fields=['id'], on_delete=models.CASCADE)

This generates the following SQL, which does not have a foreign key constraint
CREATE TABLE "myapp_parent" ("id" text NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE "myapp_child" ("id" text PRIMARY KEY, "data" jsonb NOT NULL, "parent_id" text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (("data" ->> 'parent_id')) STORED);

Notes:

I use Postgres.
I don't want to depend on pre_save and post_save signals, because I'll be inserting it using bulk_create, which doesn't support them.
I want to keep the column generated, to maintain integrity. Please don't suggest to not use generated columns.
I prefer to not write custom SQL in migrations by hand, unless absolutely necessary.

Thank you in advance <3
Edit 1
If possible, I would like to use it as if it was a ForeignKey, for example
parent = Parent.objects.get(id='1')
print(parent.child_set.count())
print(parent.child_set.all())

child = Child.objects.get(id='1')
print(child.parent.name) # assume the parent has a name


Just create a custom constraint class GeneratedForeignKey that extends Django's BaseConstraint. This class will generate the SQL for creating a foreign key constraint on our generated field.
Also add a constraints list to the Child model's Meta class, which includes our custom GeneratedForeignKey constraint.
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.constraints import BaseConstraint

class GeneratedForeignKey(BaseConstraint):
    def __init__(self, field, to, to_field):
        self.field = field
        self.to = to
        self.to_field = to_field
        super().__init__(name=f'fk_{field}_{to._meta.db_table}')

    def constraint_sql(self, model, schema_editor):
        remote_table = self.to._meta.db_table
        remote_col = self.to_field
        local_col = self.field
        return f'FOREIGN KEY ({local_col}) REFERENCES {remote_table}({remote_col})'

    def create_sql(self, model, schema_editor):
        return f'ALTER TABLE {model._meta.db_table} ADD CONSTRAINT {self.name} {self.constraint_sql(model, schema_editor)}'

    def remove_sql(self, model, schema_editor):
        return f'ALTER TABLE {model._meta.db_table} DROP CONSTRAINT {self.name}'

    def deconstruct(self):
        path = '%s.%s' % (self.__class__.__module__, self.__class__.__name__)
        return (path, (), {'field': self.field, 'to': self.to, 'to_field': self.to_field})

class Parent(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)

class Child(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    data = models.JSONField()
    parent_id = models.GeneratedField(
        expression=models.functions.Cast(F('data__parent'), output_field=models.TextField()),
        output_field=models.TextField(),
        db_persist=True
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            GeneratedForeignKey(field='parent_id', to=Parent, to_field='id')
        ]


Thank you, but how can I also have the same API as a ForeignKey, like parent.child_set or child.parent.whatever?

I don't understand give me an example

Updated the question
